# Relation between vertices and edges in a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, trees

I know the following relation between vertices and edges of a tree -

**Any connected graph(undirected) with n vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree.**

My question is suppose I have an undirected connected graph with n vertices. Then is it possible that I can have more or less than $n-1$ edges and still get a tree?

I tried making all possible trees with $4$ vertices. So far I am also getting trees which have more than $n-1$ edges along with n-1 edges trees. So I suppose we can have more than $n-1$ edges. But this is just a hit and trial thing. Is this true for any finite number of vertices?

Comment: If you have more than n-1 edges, then it is not a tree.

Comment: And less than $n-1$ edges is not possible if you require the graph to be connected

Comment: "So far I am also getting trees which have more than n-1 edges along with n-1 edges trees." Show us one tree with > n-1 edges.

Comment: @ peter.petrov - Draw a square and join the diagonal vertices. Then remove any boundary edge. Isn't this a tree?

Comment: @Dark_Knight : No, that's two fused triangles? I'm curious now how you define a tree? I would say a graph without cycles, where a cycle is a path that starts and ends in the same vertex.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is suppose I have an undirected connected graph with n vertices. Then is it possible that I can have more or less than n-1 edges?

Of course you can have **more** than $n-1$ edges. The graph won't be a tree, but in general, you can have at most ${n\choose 2}$ edges in a graph with $n$ vertices. For example, a full graph on $3$ vertices has $\frac{3\cdot2}{2}=3$ edges, which is more than $n-1=2$.

You cannot have a *connected* graph with less than $n-1$ edges, however.

Also, you claim:

> So far I am also getting trees which have more than n-1 edges along with n-1 edges trees

This is simply false. You are getting **graphs** with more than $n-1$ edges, but they are most certainly **not** trees. There is a theorem that proves that.

Comment: Can you state that theorem?

Comment: http://www.math.ryerson.ca/~danziger/professor/MTH607/Handouts/trees.pdf

Comment: @Dark_Knight I don't think the theorem has a name, but it states that an undirected graph on $n$ vertices is a tree if and only if it has $n-1$ edges

Comment: See theorem 4 there.

Comment: Ok! I think I have drawn wrong graphs and considered them as tree. Then I suppose I don't understand the concept of cycles in a graph clearly (as a tree doesn't contain a cycle). Can someon explain to me this concept of cycles?

Comment: @Dark_Knight That's a new question. Please don't pile questions.

Answer (score 1):

A tree is either defined as the graph with the minimum number of edges to be connected or as the maximum number of edges to have no circle. Both these numberes are $n-1$. So if you have a "tree" with more edges it has a circle and at least one edge can be removed, while still keeping a connected graph.

If you have n verticies it is possible to start with one vertex connected it to one of the unconnected vertices. Now take the connected part and add one edge to connected one of the unconnected vertices until every vertex is connected. This way you will get a tree and will have excactly n-1 edges (One for each vertex added to the starting vertex).